# ffmpeg: problems playing video on android

Tags: ffmpeg

(Translated) Hello! I have the following problem. I concatenate multiple ts files and convert to mp4 with ffmpeg. I do this operation multiple times in an automated way, so I don't always check the results, but whenever I do, on the computer, the result obtained is as expected. However, some videos, when played on an Android device, are seen incorrectly in any application: Chrome, Firefox, Vlc, etc. The version of ffmpeg I use is the latest. This is the command I use:

`ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel dxva2 -y -f concat -i list.txt -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4 -preset normal`

Results:

[PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmXfN.png)

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nLhs.png)

This is the output of ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version n4.3.1-26-gca55240b8c Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --disable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored.
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt470bg/unknown, progressive), 320x568, 29.50 fps, 29.50 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt470bg/unknown, progressive), 320x568, q=2-31, 29.50 fps, 29.50 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 9504 fps=8330 q=-1.0 Lsize=   24561kB time=00:07:42.26 bitrate= 435.3kbits/s speed= 405x
video:21200kB audio:3100kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.073735%
```

Not all videos are "yuv420p (tv, unknown / bt470bg / unknown, progressive)", but this should not be the problem, since other videos with this information are seen correctly on Android.

To correct this type of video I do the following:

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -i list.txt -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4`

So I get the video to play correctly both on pc and Android. Unfortunately, automating the process by always using this last line occasionally causes problems (starting file 40MB, ending file> 1GB, more than 2 hours)

I would like, if possible, help me identify which videos will be viewed incorrectly on Android. Thank you very much in advance. Finally, this is the answer that ffmpeg gives when executing the line with which I fix the file:

```
ffmpeg version n4.3.1-26-gca55240b8c Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --disable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt470bg/unknown, progressive), 320x568, 29.50 fps, 29.50 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] 264 - core 161 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=22.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'd.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x568, q=-1--1, 29.50 fps, 15104 tbn, 29.50 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
More than 1000 frames duplicated    8960kB time=00:02:06.74 bitrate= 579.1kbits/s dup=999 drop=0 speed=15.7x
frame=13638 fps=468 q=-1.0 Lsize=   32033kB time=00:07:42.20 bitrate= 567.8kbits/s dup=4134 drop=0 speed=15.9x
video:25547kB audio:5995kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.557852%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] frame I:87    Avg QP:19.17  size: 12750
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] frame P:4630  Avg QP:21.89  size:  4286
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] frame B:8921  Avg QP:23.89  size:   583
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] consecutive B-frames:  8.9%  8.6%  9.1% 73.4%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] mb I  I16..4: 12.2% 76.2% 11.6%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] mb P  I16..4:  3.7% 11.0%  0.8%  P16..4: 37.1% 16.2%  5.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:25.4%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.9%  0.1%  B16..8: 30.4%  3.1%  0.3%  direct: 0.8%  skip:64.2%  L0:51.4% L1:44.3% BI: 4.3%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] 8x8 transform intra:71.2% inter:66.8%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] direct mvs  spatial:99.9% temporal:0.1%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 52.5% 42.1% 5.5% inter: 9.7% 9.0% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] i16 v,h,dc,p: 19% 21%  9% 50%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 11% 13%  6%  9% 11%  9% 11%  8%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23%  9%  8%  6% 14% 14% 11%  9%  6%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 20% 23% 12%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.9% UV:0.8%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] ref P L0: 72.3% 12.2% 11.3%  2.1%  1.9%  0.2%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] ref B L0: 93.1%  5.5%  1.1%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] ref B L1: 97.6%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 000001efdbaee540] kb/s:452.67
[aac @ 000001efdbaee9c0] Qavg: 10682.834
```

Comment: All inputs listed in `list.txt` must have the same attributes for proper concatenation.

Comment: (Translated) Hello! Thanks for answering. The concatenation is done correctly, at least the final result on the computer is flawless. What attributes do you think I should check and how can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the files are all the same. But you should check to make sure they are the same because it is easy to do. Run command: `ffmpeg -n -i input0.ts -i input1.ts -i input2.ts` (each input is from `list.txt`). This command is for information only. It will not output a file. Copy and paste the complete log from this command.

Comment: This is the result, there are 187 small files so I have pasted the answer in the link below. Thanks a lot. [pastebin](https://pastebin.pl/view/78a671cf)